# Kafka 3 node cluster zookeeper fails to connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've been struggling with the 3 node Kafka cluster setup. I have looked at all the SO answers and seem to be doing everything right. However, Zookeeper fails to synchronize and therefore kafka servers don't connect.

Here is my zookeeper config

```
dataDir=/home/kafka/zookeeper/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=50
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=139.59.80.73:2888:3888
server.3=139.59.80.76:2888:3888
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

On each of the other servers I have set the server.id to 0.0.0.0 as suggested in one of the SO answers. So server.2 will have 0.0.0.0 on the second machine. I have double checked the myid file in the data directory to have the corresponding ids as well.

Even after waiting for a while zookeeper services don't sychronize and I keep seeing these exceptions:

```
2017-07-31 12:40:49,110] WARN Cannot open channel to 1 at election address /139.59.80.4:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:562)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:538)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:452)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:433)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What bothers me is that I can telnet to each other machine on port 2181 but zookeeper service fails to connect. Totally perplexed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a port issue. The following ports 2888 and 3888 have to be open. I had disabled IPTables on Linux but that never seemed to work. I moved to AWS and opened the two ports, zookeeper started fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed zookeeper in ensemble mode on 4 machine cluster on RedHat Linux. I was having the same issue, after trying everything form stackoverflow what i did was turning off iptables and firewall on all machines but still there was error, after a few thoughts i tired enabling passwordless ssh for all machines and this solved my problem now my zookeper's are up and running on all 4 machines

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question but I have had the same issue and want to share my solution. I had this problem in Centos 7.

First of all you can telnet to ip_addr:3888 to be sure to not reaching that host/port:

```
telnet ip_addr 3888
telnet ip addr 2888
```

Secondly you can stop firewall and then telnet again to be sure that it is a firewall problem:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

If it works after that, then it is absolutely a firewall issue.
To solve the problem you should open the ports:

```
 sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3888/tcp --permanent
 sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp --permanent
 sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```